# Creating a Bundle outside src/

Tags: symfony, bundle, src

I have created a bundle with symfony 2.3 but in this case (cause my teacher asked to me) outside `src/` folder so I have `../symfony/fuentes/NameBundle` instead of `../symfony/src/NameBundle`. The new line appears in AppKernel and my new bundle appears on `routing.yml`, but when I try to launch the server

```
Bundle generation

Generating the bundle code: OK
Checking that the bundle is autoloaded: FAILED
Confirm automatic update of your Kernel [yes]?
Enabling the bundle inside the Kernel: OK
Confirm automatic update of the Routing [yes]?
Importing the bundle routing resource: OK

The command was not able to configure everything automatically.
You must do the following changes manually.

- Edit the composer.json file and register the bundle
  namespace in the "autoload" section:
```

I have edit autoload and tried a lot of things (looking for here) but it appears the same error always.

```
C:\Users\Akenateb\Documents\UOC\AULAMENTOR\Symfony>php app/console server:run 127.0.0.1:8080
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AulaMentor\ExdosBundle\AulaMentorExdosBundle' not found in C:\Users\Akenateb\Documents\UOC\AULAMENTOR\Symfony\app\AppKernel.php on line 20
```

Can someone help me? I'm really stuck with it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would he ask something like that?

Comment: It also seems like you are running app/console generate:bundle command?

Comment: i.am.michiel - cause I am doing an excercise

Comment: Cerad - Yes I have used generate:bundle command with no problem

Comment: @i.am.michiel Imagine a situtation you have an isolated local bundle made yourself, but you don't want it to put into a git reopository, at least yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I want to thanks to the people who has answered. Here is what we have to do if we want to create a bundle outside 'src' folder, for example in 'fuentes' > '..Symfony/fuentes'.

If you have create with 'generate:bundle' I suggest you accept when the generator ask you if you want to create the complete structure, if you have create a bundle with generator goto step 3.

1- Make sure you have registered bundle in AppKernel and It exists there a line like this:

**new YourProject\NameprojectBundle\YourProjectNameprojectBundle(),**

2- Make sure you have adding a route to your app/config/routing and 'routing.yml' has you new bundle route, like this (you can add a prefix to your url, in this case fuentes):

**your_project_name:

    resource: "@YourProjectNameprojectBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"

    prefix:   /fuentes**

3- We edit 'app/autoload.php' and we add this line:

**$loader->add('YourProject',realpath(__DIR__.'/../fuentes'));**

Finally we can update assets doing with command line:
*php app/console assets:install web*

Hope it helps to someone.
Best Regards.

Comment: With the recent Symfony versions, the --shared argument must be added when using the 'generate:bundle' command.

Answer (score 1):

Do exactly as said in the comment:

```
Edit the composer.json file and register the bundle namespace in the "autoload" section
```

The  `src` folder is automatically loaded using PSR convention. If you set classes outside of the src folder, they have to be declared as well.

Comment: i.am.michiel - I have tried it  already(of course) editing symfony/composer.json It doesn´t work 4me, as a matter of fact I have tried so many things but It does not fix this problem. You said "they have to be declared as well. " ok, but how?

Answer (score 0):

In your `composer.json` file you can add another element in the `autoload` section. Here's an example that I think will work for your use case:

```json
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "NameBundle\\": "fuentes/",
      "": "src/"
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to add simply **another bundle outside your Symfony project**, when we don't want to mess up with composer.json file.

The 2 first points are the same as in the Michael J.'s answer. Now to the 3rd point:

Say, we need to add a **OurCompany/SomeBundle** residing in the other project, which relative path is **../../OtherProject/src/OurCompany/SomeBundle** to **CurrentProject/app** dir.

So we add this bundle to the CurrentProject application this way:

```
$loader->add('OurCompany\\SomeBundle', realpath(__DIR__.'/../../OtherProject/src'));
```

PLEASE NOTICE how the slashes and backslashes should be used (the remaining / or \ at the end doesn't matter, it's smart enough to figure it out).

And for the whole namespace to be loaded (all bundles namespaces in the other project available in CurrentProject):

```
$loader->add('OurCompany', realpath(__DIR__.'/../../OtherProject/src'));
```